# corrupt azure sdk not recognising local storage

Tags: azure-storage, azure-sdk-.net, azure-storage-emulator

I've accidentally deleted some of the files required for azure local storage to work. the azure storage explorer no longer recognises my local dev storage (remote is fine)  How can I recover from this ?  I've tried to reinstall the sdk (3.1) but the web platform installer wont let me as its already installed.  I don't have a repair option, now I'm stumped.  There doesn't seem to be an uninstall option for azure sdk either !

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to uninstall sdk .Here are solutions I found could be used to remove them.

1. In the "**Add/Remove Programs**" list, Microsoft Azure xxxxx and are in the middle of the list,you can remove them easily.

2.Go to `C:\Windows\Installer` and uninstall from the context menu on every .msi file that has "Azure" in the description,maybe the description is a hash-like name ,you could add the **Subject** column in Windows Explorer, then you can see the description.

3.Use the  tool "[Total-Uninstaller](https://github.com/tsasioglu/Total-Uninstaller)".

After you uninstall them you can reinstall sdk .If you couldn't remove them or still have questions ,please let me know.